# getRectsBeingDrawn returns NULL

Tags: macos, gpu, calayer, nsview, metal

I have custom `NSView` class which I am porting from OpenGL to Metal for GPU rendering. A lot of places in the code, earlier we used to call `setNeedsDisplayInRect` with an invalidated rect on the `NSView`, which I queried during the call to `drawRect` for rendering final content to the screen.

For moving to Metal, I have added a `CAMetalLayer` to my custom `NSView` class. With the addition of this `CAMetalLayer`, `getRectsBeingDrawn` returns `NULL`.

1. Are we saying that `getRectsBeingDrawn` only works for non-layer/non-metal layer backed NSViews?

Moreover, I also see a `setNeedsDisplayInRect` in `CALayer`, but I don't see a getter like `getRectsBeingDrawn` in `CALayer`.

2. Should I move to `setNeedsDisplayInRect` in `CALayer` for dirty rects in case of layer backed views? But, then again how do I retrieve those dirty rects?

Comment: hello, i have the same problem, porting my openGL app to metal and getRectsBeingDrawn returns NULL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057910/why-my-mtkview-is-drawn-like-if-there-is-a-dark-overlay-on-the-top-of-it

Comment: @loki honestly, I still don't know what is the correct way to do it.