# Why my MTKview is drawn like if there is a dark overlay on the top of it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, metal, mtkview

I'm under macOS and I create an `MTKView`, and I set this MTKView as a **subview** of the `ContentView` of my `NSWindow`.

when I'm inside my `MTKView.drawRect` method and when I call `NSView(Super).getRectsBeingDrawn` it returns me nothing! why?

But my main problem is that the `MTKView` is drawn darker (like there is something darker on the top of it)

[image]

I must have something like this instead:

[image]

Any idea what can cause this darker effect?